# Printing leading '-' in C?

Tags: c, format, printf

i was trying to print numbers in right justified format:

suppose,

input:

```
printf("\n%d", 1234567);
printf("\n%07d", 5);
```

output:

```
1234567
0000005
```

but what if i want to print

```
------5
```

i'm confused here, as '-' is used for left justification

i tried using

```
printf("\n%\-d", 5);
```

but console shows

```
warning: unknown escape sequence: '\-'
```

Comment: You can't. Will need to implement it yourself. One simple way would be to use `sprintf` and then run over resulting string replacing the leading zeros with `-`s.

Answer (score 2):

This is one way to do it, taking advantage of the `%.*s` format specifier.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void dashed(int width, int num)
{
    char buff[12];          // enough for 32-bit int
    int len = width - sprintf(buff, "%d", num);
    printf("%.*s%s", len < 0 ? 0 : len, "-----------", buff);
}

int main(void)
{
    dashed(7, 5);           // 1 digit
    puts("");
    dashed(7, 55);          // 2 digits
    puts("");
    dashed(7, 555555);      // 6 digits
    puts("");
    dashed(7, 5555555);     // 7 digits
    puts("");
    dashed(7, 55555555);    // 8 digits
    puts("");
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
------5
-----55
-555555
5555555
55555555
```

Answer (score 1):

There's one rough idea that does what you actually want. Why not count the number of digits in the given variable and print the backspace character and print back the number like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int num = 1234;
    int temp = num;
    int count = 0;

    if (num < 0)
        puts("The number is negative, don't ignore the last dash");

    printf("--------");

    while (temp != 0) {
        temp /= 10;
        ++count; // it'll count till '4' because 1234 has 4 digits
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        printf("\b"); // so '4' backspaces

    printf("%d\n", num); // the dashes will be replaced with the number

    return 0;
}
```

A sample test case is as follows (depends upon 'num'):

```
----1234
```

Comment: I think it might not be working on every console type

Comment: oooo never tough of printing \b to "unprint" what already was printed! anyway your code should take on consideration that we may want to print negative numbers and considerate the minus sign of the number as the number width

Comment: @Tsak how will the reader know it is a negative number?

Comment: well in your exemple you set the number so you know its positive, but we can imagine the the nb could be entered by an user or whatever, in this case there's juste a little line or two to add to handle this i think (something like "count -= (num < 0);" before the for loop

Comment: @Tsak I mean how will the reader know if `------5` is `5` or `-5`?

Comment: oo yes, ur right, this is why it would be better to justify with spaces as printf can easily do (printf("%7d", nb);) but hey, printing dashes is what is asked ^^ so either you have to handle it by printing the correct number of (confusing) dashes, either you have to handle it by not printing any dashes in the case  where nb is a negative number :p

Comment: @WeatherVane now user will know the negative values.

Answer (score 0):

i don't think printf has something which would do this, you can try to have fun by writing your own printf ^^
you may have to put a loop to print the right number of - signs before printing your number, and you may need another function to determine the right number of - sign to print depending on the desired width and the width of number, something like:

```
int get_nb_width(int nb, int base)
{
    int ret;
    if (base < 2)
        return (0);
    ret = 1 + (nb < 0);
    for (;nb / base != 0;nb /= base)
        ret++;
    return (ret);
}
void print_minus_signs(int nb, int total_width, int base)
{
    int width;

    if (get_nb_width(nb, base) == 0)
        return ;
    for (width = get_nb_width(nb, base); width < total_width; width++)
        printf("-");
}
int main()
{
    int nb = -12;
    int width = 7;

    print_minus_signs(nb, width, 10);
    printf("%d", nb);
    return (0);
}
```

this code should print :

```
-----12
```

(four '-' printed by the function, and '-12' printed by the printf)

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem:

```
printf("\n%\-d", 5);
          ^^
```

The `%` expects one of the following `printf` format specifiers:

> ```
> %c    character
> %d    decimal (integer) number (base 10)
> %e    exponential floating-point number
> %f    floating-point number
> %i    integer (base 10)
> %o    octal number (base 8)
> %s    a string of characters
> %u    unsigned decimal (integer) number
> %x    number in hexadecimal (base 16)
> %%    print a percent sign
> ```

you can change that statement to:

```
 printf("\-%d", 5);// to get `-5`
```

To get the number of `-` to match the number of digits in the integer, you will need to do something similar to:

```
int b=123456789;
int a;
a = b;
int min_width = 15;

while (b != 0) {
    b /= 10;     // n = n/10
    printf("\-");;
}
printf("%d", a);
```

And if the output needs to be left justified, use a width specifier:

```
b /= 10;     // n = n/10
printf("%*s", min_width, "\-");   
while (b != 0) {
    b /= 10;     // n = n/10
    printf("\-");;
}
printf("%d\n", a);
```